# Append to the end of Azure blob file in .NET Core 3.1 without downloading the entire file

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, asp.net-core-3.1

I need to append to the end of an Azure blob file, and I'm wondering if there's a way to do that without having to download the entire blob file. I've searched around but it seems like most answers were using assemblies that are now deprecated. The only way I have figured out how to do it in .NET Core 3.1 is with the code below. Is there a more efficient way to do this? I know that for my requirements, this file will eventually become very large and it will probably become inefficient to download the entire file just to append a quick line to the end of it.

I'm using the assembly Azure.Storage.Blobs

```
public static void BlobAppender()
    {
        BlobClient bc = new BlobClient("my azure connection string", "mycontainer", "myblobfile");

        var testStream = bc.OpenRead();
        StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();

        using (StreamReader sm = new StreamReader(testStream))
        {
            string temp;
            while ((temp = sm.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                SB.AppendLine(temp);
            }
        }

        //I append the line here, then reupload.
        SB.AppendLine("My new line");

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SB.ToString());
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

        bc.Upload(stream, overwrite: true);

    }
```

Comment: is using [Append Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs#about-append-blobs) and option?

Comment: It is, yes. I read about that as well and couldn't quite find anything for appending to the blob that wasn't deprecated.

Comment: At minimum, the REST API is not deprecated. I don't know if there are nice sdk wrappers but if you can speak HTTP, you can perform an append.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Append Blobs` as they are meant for that purpose only. Here's the sample code to do so using version `12.8.0` of `Azure.Storage.Blobs` SDK.

```
    static async Task AppendBlobExample()
    {
        string connectionString = "connection-string";
        string containerName = "container-name";
        string blobName = "blob-name";
        string content = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus pulvinar auctor vehicula. Proin vitae ante risus. Quisque fringilla orci eros, nec fermentum ipsum blandit et. Curabitur imperdiet tristique magna non vehicula. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed efficitur magna nisl, vitae venenatis leo semper nec. Nulla consequat lorem sapien, sed aliquam lectus dictum non. Morbi ac pulvinar justo, sit amet cursus turpis. In dictum odio non tellus aliquam viverra. Nunc vel vestibulum nulla. Ut mollis ultrices dignissim. Donec tellus nibh, bibendum suscipit felis sed, elementum auctor est. Donec ex nibh, pellentesque vitae odio ut, ornare pulvinar odio.";

        var appendBlobClient = new AppendBlobClient(connectionString, containerName, blobName);
        if (!await appendBlobClient.ExistsAsync())
        {
            await appendBlobClient.CreateAsync();
        }
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)))
        {
            await appendBlobClient.AppendBlockAsync(ms);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Worked beautifully, thank you. For those that stumble in here, the namespace required for this in .NET Core 3.1 is Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized

Comment: Hi, I am  currently testing this logic, but it is not working well, when I tried to add a new string in the end of the file it add in the same line, no idea why, could someone help me with this?

Comment: @polzka90 - Please ask a separate question. Thanks.